# Python 3 CardDAV client or library

Tags: python, client, carddav

Is there any [RFC 6352](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352) comliant CardDAV client software or library compatible to Python 3?

I am aware of [pyCardDAV](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyCardDAV/) but this package is not yet python 3 ready.